# What is wrong with this SQLite Create Statement

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am not able to create a SQLite table in an Android project using the SQL statement below, What am I doing wrong with this Sqlite statement?

```
public class CustomerSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DBNAME = "Customer.db";
    private static final int DBVERSION = 1;     


    //Create constants for column names of the Customer Table
    private final static String TABLE_NAME = "custTable";
    private final static String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private final static String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private final static String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    private final static String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
    private final static String COLUMN_UID = "card_uid2";
    private final static String COLUMN_DATE_CREATED = "enrollment_date";
    private final static String COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED = "last_transaction_date";
    private final static String COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE = "initial_value";
    private final static String COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE = "current_value";  


    private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_UID + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT, " +
                COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT, " +
                COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE + " NUMERIC, " +
                COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE + " NUMERIC " +
                ")";            

    public CustomerSQLiteHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CUSTOMER_TABLE);  
        android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Table created");

    }
```

It fails in the Emulator with the error message below, obtained from the LogCat,

```
05-08 00:14:41.435: E/SQLiteLog(2434): (1) near ",": syntax error
05-08 00:14:41.435: D/AndroidRuntime(2434): Shutting down VM
05-08 00:14:41.435: W/dalvikvm(2434): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f11648)
05-08 00:14:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 00:14:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(2434): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.txsystems.valuecard/com.txsystems.valuecard.app.EnrollActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE custTable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT, phone TEXT, card_uid2 TEXT, enrollment_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT, last_transaction_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT, initial_value NUMERIC, current_value NUMERIC )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Default` keyword you also need to provide a `default` value.that you missed in your query.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I added current_timestamp after default and the table was created

Answer (score 3):

If you use `DEFAULT`, you must supply a default value after the keyword and not `,`.

Change to something like

```
private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_UID + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, " +
            COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE + " NUMERIC, " +
            COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE + " NUMERIC " +
            ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the DEFAULT a value

```
private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_UID + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '', " +   <---
                COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '', " +   <---
                COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE + " NUMERIC, " +
                COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE + " NUMERIC " +
                ")";
```